# Keyboard is not working after Windows 10 update

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, windows-update

Edit: problem unsolved as of yet (new keyboard ordered)

The lights are on but pressing keys does nothing. I've tried everything and it doesn't respond. I did a system restore to before the update and still nothing. It happened immediately after the computer restarted after the update. I tried the keyboard in two different Windows 10 computers and it worked right away. I tried different usb ports but nothing. Before doing a system restore, I copied the system32 keyboard sys drivers from the computers where it works and used them to replace the ones where it doesn't work but still nothing. If I go to Bluetooth and Other Devices it lists the keyboard. I have used this keyboard on this computer with Windows 10 for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried the keyboard in two different Windows 10 computers and it
> worked right away. I tried different USB ports but nothing.

Try the following:

**(1)  DISM / SFC**

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.  Run:

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /StartComponentCleanup

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth

SFC /SCANNOW

Restart and Check.

**(2) Windows 10 Repair Install**:

If DISM fails, update ALL drivers (manufacturer's Driver Update App) and do a Repair Install

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Start with the option to Keep Everything.

> Notes for Repair Install:
>
> 1. This process will upgrade all applicable drivers.
> 2. This process will make you uninstall incompatible software
> 3. This process will not fix damaged User Profiles. Must use Keep

Nothing

**(3) Everything fails to fix:**

Back up the system and reinstall Windows and/or try a **different/new  keyboard**.

Comment: When I try the first line of your first solution, I get this error:
The operation could not be completed due to pending operations. Btw, I noticed that Windows didn't restore to before the main update I installed yesterday but to a smaller one that came right after. I might have to restore to before the major one. Although it took such a long time to restore to before the small update I want to try your solutions first.

Comment: Try the Repair Install. That will correct update and software issues. Be sure to do Driver Updates.

Comment: Did both the Windows repair and the first alternative and still nothing. This is so strange.

Comment: I amended my answer. Strange indeed. But when everything fails, back up and reinstall Windows . Possibly a different keyboard might work even though this one does work on other computers. You could have a hardware error, but I would try fresh install of Windows first.

Comment: I actually think I reinstalled Windows. When I tried the media creation tool, it gave me two options, to download Windows 10 and reinstall in place (think it said upgrade), or download an image. I didn't hit upgrade btw, I clicked download. The top of the window that appeared said media creation so I'm pretty sure I didn't make a mistake.

Comment: Btw, some more info: I searched for keyboard in the taskbar search and when I clicked on it, it says "The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable. Click Ok to again, or enter an alternate path folder containing the installation package 'mkc.msi' in the box below." I had gotten this message before right after it stopped working but for some reason it went away. It reappeared after trying different things. The default path starts with i:\. I don't have an i drive.

Comment: This is what I clicked on to, I believe, reinstall Winfows: https://prnt.sc/unxvak

This is the message I got when I clicked on "keyboard": https://prnt.sc/unxwkl

Comment: I mentioned in my answer to do all driver updates and you should do that including BIOS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113407/discussion-between-srcp-and-john).